# Bad performance when not selecting a specific column from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2016 SP1. I have a view `Users` that goes like

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS DataModelID, *
FROM            
    (Some query) AS tbl
```

I then select from it

```
SELECT 
    U1.ID UserId, U1.IdentityNumber IdentityNumber,
    U1.ArabicFirstName, U1.ArabicSecondName
FROM
    USERS U1
LEFT JOIN 
    USERS U2 ON U1.IdentityNumber = U2.IdentityNumber
             AND U1.ID <> U2.ID
             AND U1.RoleId = 2
WHERE 
    U2.ID IS NOT NULL 
    AND U1.IdentityNumber <> '' 
    AND PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', U1.IdentityNumber) = 1
```

The thing here is with the above query when selecting * or include column DataModelID it runs in 3 secs but when selecting any columns without this one it runs in more than 2 mins.

Why is this happening, running faster when including a column?

I tried everything for the cash to clear it and run multiple times and it has the same results

Comment: For some quick relief, you might want to examine the query plan inside SSMS.

Comment: Its most likely that the SQL Optimiser is using a different index. Can you show us your execution plan for both quries?

Comment: You probably don't need to have the `ROW_NUMBER()` outside of your subquery, if that's all your outer query is doing. You should be able to do the window function inside the query itself.

Comment: `AND PATINDEX( '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',U1.IdentityNumber) = 1` is not sargable

Comment: This `U2.ID IS NOT NULL` turns `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN` and the second is preferred for performance reasons. `And U1.RoleId = 2` is confusing within join predicate - it isn't related to join condition, so it should be placed into `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If you check for U2.ID not null then should use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: also your derived table in the view isn't needed... and select * in a view is not wise since if the underlying table changes, your downstream queries which rely on this view could break.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the `actual` execution plan there is no way to say for sure but as @mvisser  mentioned - the likely cause is that the optimizer is choosing a better index when you do a 
`SELECT *` or include column DataModelID than when you don't. There are a number of solutions here, one suggestion would be to look at the execution plan for the queries that run in 3 seconds, note what index is being used and use an [index hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017#examples) (see section G) to force the optimizer to use that index in your queries that don't reference those columns. *I would not suggest this though* - there are too many unanswered variables to consider this a viable option.

**Here's what I recommend:**

First, as @Lukasz Szozda mentioned, this is not SARGable:

```
AND PATINDEX( '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',U1.IdentityNumber) = 1
```

But this is:

```
U1.IdentityNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

So I'd fix that first. Next, the fastest, most sure-fire way to resolve this is to simply include DataModelID in your queries even if you don't need them. You can either filter that column out at the application level or create a stored proc that populates a temp table then, for the final result set, you can retrieve your results from that temp table excluding DataModelID.

**OPTION #2**

You can create an Indexed View on you USERS table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwUSERS_clean
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT U1.ID, UserId, U1.IdentityNumber IdentityNumber,
       U1.ArabicFirstName, U1.ArabicSecondName, DataModelID, U2.IdentityNumber
FROM USERS U1
WHERE U2.ID IS NOT NULL 
AND U1.IdentityNumber <> '' 
AND U1.IdentityNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
GO
```

Then create a unique, clustered index on it. Next you would change the query that you posted to reference your indexed view (*e.g. change both references to `USERS` to `dbo.vwUSERS_clean WITH (NOEXPAND)`*).

Note that ROW_NUMBER is not allowed in indexed views but, if you make ID your clustered index (or the first column in a composite clustered index) then there will be no cost to Adding `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ORDER BY ID` to queries that reference that Indexed view.

Comment: I put the PATINDEX because LIKE took much more time